# Visual Studio Code - Knockout - Cannot find name 'ko'

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, visual-studio-code

I'm new to Knockout and Visual Studio Code (on a Mac).

I created an html file and within it, had my `<script>` with all my knockout code. All good. I then created a separate code.js file, and moved the code into it.

However, now all my ko. references are underlined as 'warnings' with the message saying that the editor "`Cannot find name 'ko'`".

How do I get Visual Studio Code to 'know' about 'Knockout'.

Comment: Do you have a `<script>` line in your HTML document, before the `<script>` tag that calls your Knockout code, that imports the Knockout file you downloaded?  If you left that out, or if you put it after you call your Knockout code, that could give you the error you mention.

Comment: I checked and double checked. I don't have extra script tags.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your project setup you will either want to npm install [@types/knockout](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/knockout). Or you could use NuGet [knockout.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped](https://www.nuget.org/packages/knockout.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `@types/knockout` to your project/package.json via command line with `npm install --save-dev @types/knockout`